# MongoDB - running parallel promises with nodejs driver is not working with multiple databases

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I have this code where I only get result from 1 Promise, I tried each one individually by commenting one of them, they actually resolve with no error, but when they are together, i only get the result of the first one.
But not from `Promise.all`, only the `console.log` inside the Promise gets called

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var $ = mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://nobody:nobody@localhost/dbauth');
$.then(
(db) => {
    var pp = [];
    pp.push(new Promise(
     (resolve, reject) => {
        var dbx = db.db('db1');
        dbx.authenticate('user1', 'user1').then((x) => {
            console.log(x); // true
            var o = dbx.stats();
            o.then(
               (result) => {
                  console.log(result);
                  resolve(result);
               }
            ).catch(
               (err) => {
                   reject(err);
               }
            );
        });
     }));

    pp.push(new Promise(
     (resolve, reject) => {
       var dbx = db.db('db2');
       dbx.authenticate('user2', 'user2').then((x) => {
            console.log(x);
            var o = dbx.stats();
            o.then(
               (result) => {
                  console.log(result);
                  resolve(result);
               }
            ).catch(
               (err) => {
                   reject(err);
               }
            );
       });
    }));

    return Promise.all(pp).then(
        (res) => {
            res.forEach(console.log);
        }
    ).catch(console.log);
}).catch(console.log);
```

what prints is this

```
true // from console.log(x); of promise db1 -> auth successful
true // from console.log(x); of promise db2 -> auth successful
{ db: 'db1',
  collections: 2,
  views: 0,
  objects: 0,
  avgObjSize: 0,
  dataSize: 0,
  storageSize: 8192,
  numExtents: 0,
  indexes: 2,
  indexSize: 8192,
  ok: 1 } // from console.log(res) of promise db2
```

but the same code will work fine if I remove this part from the code from **both** promises and call `resolve(x)` instead

```
                o.then(
                   (result) => {
                      console.log(result);
                      resolve(result);
                   }
                ).catch(
                   (err) => {
                       reject(err);
                   }
                );
```

why actually the promise is being executed before it comes to `Promise.all` ?

---

### UPDATE -> THIS DOESN'T WORK

I changed my code to look like this, but it didn't work too

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var $ = mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://nobody:nobody@localhost/dbauth');
$.then((db) => {

    var db1 = db.db('db1');
    var db2 = db1.db('db2');

    var p1 = db1.authenticate('user1', 'user2').then((x) => {
        return db1.stats();
    });

    var p2 = db2.authenticate('user2', 'user2').then((x) => {
        return db2.stats();
    });

    return Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(console.log);
}).catch(console.log);
```

---

### UPDATE 2 -> THIS WORKS BUT IT IS NOT WHAT I WANT

I changed my code to be like this, and it worked! ... but this is not what I want, what I want is to have both Promises executed in an asynchronous way

```
var $ = mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://nobody:nobody@localhost/dbauth');
$.then((db) => {
    var db1 = db.db('db1');
    var p1 = db1.authenticate('user1', 'user2').then((x) => {
        return db1.stats().then(
            (res) => {
                console.log(res);
                var db2 = db1.db('db2');
                return db2.authenticate('user2', 'user2').then((x) => { 
                    return db2.stats();
                });
            }
        );
    });
    p1.then(console.log);
}).catch(console.log);
```

It seams it is MongoDB issue ?

---

## UPDATE 3 -> THIS DOESN'T WORK

```
const px = (dbx, user, pass) => {
    return dbx.authenticate(user, pass).then((x) => {
        return dbx.stats()
    });
}

var $ = mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://nobody:nobody@localhost/dbauth');
$.then((db) => {
    Promise.all([
        px(db.db('db1'), 'user1', 'user1'),
        px(db.db('db2'), 'user2', 'user2')
    ]).then(console.log);
}).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: avoid the promise constructor anti-pattern ... `dbx.authenticate` returns a promise, no need to wrap that in a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX i changed my code, but it didn't work too

Comment: `UPDATE 2` - they are still asynchronous, but in series rather than parallel

Comment: by the way - your code is simply a very long winded version of https://jsfiddle.net/y8yajo12/ :p

Comment: @JaromandaX it was the result of experimenting directly on the terminal, i did  what you said but still not working

Comment: that just sounds wrong - unless it's, as you say, some Mongo issue with parallel requests

Comment: Does https://jsfiddle.net/y8yajo12/1/ work any better (that's basically the same as what you do in UPDATE 2, except it results in both results in the final then)

Comment: @JaromandaX No, actually, in my code I will have only one db instance that will change based on user api request, so this code here is just a simulation of what i expect when the api gets multiple requests at the same time, I only connect once to mongodb before starting the `httpServer` then I should use the same request to serve multiple users on multiple databases

Comment: @JaromandaX check this to understand what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/y8yajo12/2/

Comment: you do realise there's a typo (missing ,) in my code examples, right, between p1 and p2 - also, I dont' see how the code in the fiddle demonstrates anything related to the question - but I'm probably not understanding what you're trying to say.

Comment: here is the correct code https://jsfiddle.net/y8yajo12/3/, Imagine 100 Users call `GET /stats/:db:/:user/:pass` at the same time WITH different parameters ... I'm just worrying that it will just be the same as executing parallel promises ?

Comment: yeah, I don't know how that sort of thing works with mongo and node etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a MongoDB issue, we cannot run concurrent `auth` operations

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-984

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your question at all. But, this:

```
return Promise.all([pp]).then(
    (res) => {
        res.forEach(console.log);
    }
).catch(console.log);
```

Seems erroneous becasue `pp` is an array I believe.  Meaning it be like: `[[whatever is in pp]]`

Comment: sorry no that was a mistake of editing the question, actually i also try `Promise.all(pp)`